# Не работает присваивание ключа массива с помощью input

Tags: php, html

Имеется форма, с помощью которой вводятся значения в input, который является массивом

```
<textarea class="description-area" name="field[stext]"></textarea>
<textarea class="description-area" name="field[ftext]"></textarea>
```

...итд

Но не получается получить массив вида `["stext" => "Тест1", "ftext" => "Текст2", ...]`

Выходит ошибка: `Undefined index: stext, Undefined index: ftext`

Работает только вывод, когда PHP сам инкрементирует ключ:

```
name="field[]" ["0" => "Текст1", ...]
```

Но необходимо, чтоб был определенный ключ для дальнейших операций

HTML:

```
<form action="data.php" method="POST">
<textarea class="description-area" name="field[stext]"></textarea>
<textarea class="description-area" name="field[ftext]"></textarea>
<button class="save-btn" name="edit">Изменить</button>
</form>
```

data.php:

```
if (isset($_POST["edit"])) {
// внутри array должно быть так "stext" => "Текст1", "ftext" => "Текст2",а получается только так "0" => "Текст1" итд
$column = array($_POST["field"]);
}
```

Comment: вам несколько пар ключей надо таких создать или что? какую структуру $_REQUEST вы хотите получить?

Comment: Ну как минимум в кавычки ключ взять.

Comment: @teran, вообще будут несколько ключей. Я показал только пару, чтоб было ясно. Нужно этот $_POST передать в array(key => value)

Comment: @PavelNazarian, не работает. Я уже пробовал многие методы с интернета. Все та же ошибка

Comment: код нормальный покажите, что за чем идёт, тут не очень ясно

Comment: @PavelNazarian показал

Comment: что-то не верю я, что  `print_r($_POST['field'])` дает 0-индексированный массив

Answer (score 1):

это вопрос про отладку, а не про код. вам надо сделать print_r($_POST); на приёме формы, и вы увидите, что ваши данные не в $_POST['stext'] а $_POST['field']['stext']

Comment: Для отладки лучше использовать var_dump, потому что он сообщит больше подробностей о переменной. В выводе print_r не отличить строку от числа, true от 1, не увидеть false и null.

Answer (score 1):

Сперва любопытный факт. Стандартный application/x-www-form-urlencoded не предусматривает вложенных структур. Там есть только *имя* и *значение*. Однако php придаёт особое значение квадратным скобкам в имени (это не стандарт, в других языках квадратные скобки не парсятся). Запустите следующий скрипт, чтобы посмотреть как это работает.

```
<?php // index.php

// php -S localhost:8080

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="field[stext]"></textarea>
    <textarea name="field[ftext]"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

То что надо!

В таком случае, что же не так с вашим кодом? Сложно сказать наверняка. Скорее всего какая-нибудь досадная опечатка (например невидимый символ в названии `field­[ftext]`) или ошибка в вашем коде, который работает с данными. Может быть массив $_POST модифицирует какой-то код прежде чем вы пытаетесь извлекать данные. Может быть у вас какая-то уникальная сборка php, которая больше не парсит квадратные скобки (это совсем невероятный случай).

Вам правильно советуют научиться отлаживать код. Познакомьтесь хотя бы с таким примитивным методом как *dump and die*.

Answer (score 1):

Вам переменной `$column` присваивать прямо значение реквеста, а не оборачивать его в массив. Оно и так есть ассоциативным массивом

```
$column = $_POST["field"];
echo $column["stext"]);
echo $column["ftext"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо)

С отладкой знаком, только она не помогала. Может быть все скэшировалось и сохранялся прежний результат?

Не знаю, что происходило, но по итогу перезагрузка сервера и браузера помогли решить проблему